# Rails edit routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This error is creeping in on more than one occasion and i can't seem to pin point it.
error log:

```
    undefined method `medium_path' for #<#<Class:0x0000010687a788>:0x00000101d62d90>
Extracted source (around line #3):
```

media controller.

```
 class MediaController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @medias = Media.all
    end

    def show
        @media = Media.find(params[:id])
    end

    def edit
        @media = Media.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

edit.html.erb.

```
 <h1>Editing <%= @media.title %></h1>

<%= form_for(@media) do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %>
    </p>

<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
  Mediastuff::Application.routes.draw do

  root "media#index" 
  get "media" => "media#index"
  get "media/:id" => "media#show", as: "show_media"
  get "media/:id/edit" => "media#edit", as: "edit_media"



end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that error is generated from your `form_for` declaration.  In addition to what you already have in your `config/routes.rb`, you may also want to add a route for `update` action as that `form_for(@media)` is going to be an update.

Add the following to your `config/routes.rb`:

```
put "media/:id/update" => "media#update"
```

Also make sure to define `update` action in your `MediaController`.

Another option would be to use `resources` in `config/routes.rb` as a replacement to all the `media/...` routes you have:

```
Mediastuff::Application.routes.draw do
  root "media#index" 
  resources :media
end
```

And to see what path/url helpers you can use, run `rake routes` from terminal.